# Security concerns about using $_GET to fetch id from a URL

Tags: php, security

What's the industry standard for creating public profile pages on a website? I see many answers proposing a $_GET call where the user's unique id is placed in the url. Isn't this a form of security vulnerability where you're exposing your secure database unique id?

Sure I'm using PDO with binding and such, but why would I ever want to show this part of db my publically?

An aside: That being said, given a url with a username, is it standard practice to use modrewrite to redirect to a script to find the id from the username, and thus all the user info?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Why is exposing the identifier necessarily a bad or "insecure" thing?  My Stack Overflow user ID is 328193, doesn't seem to pose a problem.  Any value(s) which uniquely and unambiguously defines the record you're looking for would certainly work just as well, of course.

Comment: I think it's only you that can decide whether or not the user pk should be exposed or not. Many sites encode the id for public use. Most do not.

Comment: @David - I don't know much about this area, but my first thoughts are that I could use the user ID towards sessions hijacking - both bad and insecure.

Comment: @Knixd: Session hijacking doesn't really have anything to do with that.

Comment: @David: If a hobbyist site bases a lot of settings off of a stored session user ID without first checking the id against the db everytime then isn't it bad?

Comment: @Knixd: I don't really see what you're asking there.  If any site allows users to perform restricted actions with properly authorization that would certainly be bad.  Session hijacking would be if a 3rd party spoofed the token used for that authorization.  If your site uses predictable and unchanging values as that token, that would be bad.  But nothing to do with the user ID.

Comment: @David - I thought you could create your own session and put a user id into your best guess at what the session's user id variable name is and proceed. I didn't realize you'd have to recreate the authorization token. I suppose I'm asking what I typed in the original question, isn't this "a form of insecurity". Maybe it's better to state that using a user id in the url is always 100% secure and go from there...

Comment: @Knixd: It sounds like you're basing a lot of this on an incorrect understanding of authentication and authorization.  The user ID in a URL isn't related to security at all.  For example, you can force the URL to try to edit a different user's profile.  But the site *certainly* shouldn't accept that query string as valid authorization.  It should simply compare who you are (your logged-in self) with the record you're trying to edit (not yours) and display an error.

Comment: @David - Thanks for your help. It's probably based on my lack of knowledge surrounding session hijacking. If you put the last comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: as some tutorial website once said `user id in url = system not insecure , passwords and such in the url = system terribly insecure`

Comment: I have seen practices where an public unique id will be used only for external purposes and not be used as a foreign key of any table which probably wont expose any of the critical data even if it is compromised "to some extent". so isn't having a internal purpose id and a public id safer in these scenarios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your usernames are unique too. What kind of database are you referring to when you say "secure database". In fact any page that has user profile features (StackExchange, Popular Social Networks, etc.) exposes the user ID in the profile URLs. Just hover over your own name on this page and see your ID.

You gave yourself the correct answer: Your profile pages are **public** so there is no risk in exposing additional profile pages (by incrementing user IDs for example)

With so many professionals contributing, if this as a bad idea, StackExchange would have fixed this already.